# PHP/SQL multiple query loop

Tags: php, sql

I have a time and attendance SQL 2005 database

So every time some one clocks in it adds a new entry into the table with their UserID and a DateTime entry.

I have a second table with all the users details.

On a specific day, I can run a query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TASVR.dbo.Persons
WHERE
    UserID LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
    AND UserID NOT IN 
        (SELECT UserID
        FROM TASVR.dbo.TAData
            WHERE
                (
                DateTime > '" . $strDate . " 00:00:00' 
                AND DateTime < '" . $strDate . " 12:00:00'
                ))
ORDER BY LName ASC
```

Which returns anyone who has not clocked in or anyone who has clocked in after 12 for the given date.

Now I want to run this query over a period of 2 weeks (excluding Sat and Sun) and it to return the days they were absent (or at least the days they were present) all in the form of something useful that I can play with in PHP.

So I need a loop with some exclusions. Any ideas?

Even if I just have a list of names of anyone that was absent over the time period, then I would just create another query in a PHP loop to pull those specific people's details for the period and work from there.

### Update

I have managed to figure out how I am going to display when a person is absent over a date period using php arrays. Now if only I could work out how to get a list of UserIDs of the people that have been absent at least once in the range... For now, I have it checking against EVERY SINGLE PERSON!!! Which is time consuming to say the least.

Comment: I'd like to refer you to **[crons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)**.

Comment: Do you want a list of rows like this: PersonA date1 absent, Person1 date2 Present, PersonB date1 LateEntry

Comment: Well, that would be a report for the entire list of 100s of people, making it a bit long.

I already have a separate report for people that arrive late (was easy to work with data that exists), I just had the bosses ask for an absent list which is a lot more complicated because I need to use data that does not exist.

I want a list of people who were absent (even if it is just once) for a given date range, the rest I think I could figure out with a combination of repeat queries and php.